# How to get ZSH previous command's history number in prompt?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I'm wanting to add the previous command's history number to my prompt, as well as the exit code.

At present,

```
%h[%?]
```

Gives me the *current* history number, as well as the *last* exit code. What I'd really like is an expansion for `%h-1`, but I'm not sure if that is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, courtesy of /r/commandline on Reddit is:

```
 PS1='$[HISTCMD-1][%?] %#'
```